# How to commit repo A into repo B?

Tags: git

I have a repo named A,
and another repo named B.
Both are cloned already.

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxx/A.git
git clone https://github.com/xxxx/B.git
```

I cp B into A's directory.

```
cp B A -r
```

then

```
git add .
```

then I try git commit

```
git commit
```

I found files in B are not added into A.
How to add all files of B into A ?
And commit them.

Comment: check status ( git status ) your file added or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want to discard repo **B** you shouldn't add repositories into one another like that. You should add **B** into **A** as a [**`git submodule`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) instead, that's what the submodule mechanism has been created for.

But if you simply want a plain duplicate copy of **B** in **A**, you can proceed as follows,

Add **B** as a remote,

```
A master $ git remote add B https://github.com/xxxx/B.git
```

Fetch **B**,

```
A master $ git fetch B
```

Merge **B** (I'll assume you are interested in the master branch), into your **A** master,

```
A master $ git merge B/master
```

Resolve conflicts, if applicable, commit the result:

```
A master $ git commit
```

---

If you don't want to merge **B** into **A** master branch, simply branch `B/master` instead of the merge step, and push the resulting branch. That way B's code will be stored on a separate branch in **A**.

Answer (score 0):

We do `git add .` to add the files which are staged (Ready to be committed). If the files were  already in the staged area and some modifications were done on those files,then `git add .` could have helped you.

But in your case it seems you need to first bring your new files to staged area. Then your commit will pick those files.

Whenever new files are added in the working tree, you have to add them to staged area from unstaged area for which you have to explicitly mention the **git add directory_name/** (For example: **git add B/** ) which will add all the files in this directory to the staged area.

After this when you do `git commit`, all files under B will get added to A.
Hope this will help you !!